# Save dictionary to text file (C#)

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I want to save a dictionary to a text file in Unity3D (using C#). The dictionary contains GameObjects as keys which corresponds to lists of Vector2's.

This is my code:

```
public void SaveLevel(string LevelName) 
{
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter (LevelName+".txt"))
    {
        foreach (GameObject entity in levelStruct.Keys)
        { 
            file.WriteLine (entity.ToString () + ": " + levelStruct[entity].ToString());        
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the example file:

```
wall (UnityEngine.GameObject): System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.Vector2]
rat (UnityEngine.GameObject): System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.Vector2]
dwarf (UnityEngine.GameObject): System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.Vector2]
floor (UnityEngine.GameObject): System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.Vector2]
```

My issue is that the file needs to contain the actual items in the Vector2 list, not the list itself:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List1[UnityEngine.Vector2]
```

I want the above line to look something like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List1[(0,2),(3,1),(4,3)]
```

How would i accomplish this?

Comment: Your best and easiest call would be to convert your dictionary to JSON, most json parser will do that, then just save the json as text. Not only you get to save but you get it in a recognized format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a varaible of the specific type and get the properties you need

```
   public void SaveLevel(string LevelName) 
    {
    string res;
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter (LevelName+".txt"))
        {
            foreach (GameObject entity in levelStruct.Keys)
            { 
                foreach(Vector2 v in levelStruct[entity])){
                      res = " "+"("+v.x+"."+v.y+")";
             }
          file.WriteLine (entity.ToString () + ": " + res);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wait, wont this just write one of the list items?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Unity before, so apologies if I have misunderstood. If Vector2 is a custom class that you have created, then you can override the default ToString() method, so that it spits out whichever string you need. Alternatively, you need to access whichever property it is that you're trying to write out from the value in your dictionary. E.g (assuming Foo is your property).

```
file.WriteLine (entity.ToString() + ": " + levelStruct[entity].Foo.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont have the rep to vote up yet though. Also Vector2 is like a tuple in python if you are familiar with those, its included in the api and comes in handy when you want to represents a coordinate in a 2D environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use serializing and deserializing to save and recover your objects, because when you use ToString() function return just the name of object in most of times. I suggest you to google it but there is some resources:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

You are writing objects. When you call a ToString() on an object, you get the name of the object type. Instead, you need to do one of two things:

**#1:** If you really want to write using CSV as your code suggests:

```
  Object.Property.ToString();
```

In the case of a GameObject, you might need to use reflection to do this

```
 using System.Reflection;
 foreach(PropertyInfo p in typeof(UnityEngine.GameObject).GHetProperties()){
     Console.WriteLine(p.Name+","+p.GetType().ToString());
 }
 //repeat as necessary with fields and methods and ... as needed using System.Reflection
```

The second item is a list of vectors - same thing. For that, you'd use

```
 foreach(UnityEngine.Vector2 vect in levelStruct[entity])){
    //write ToString();
  }
```

**#2:** Learn how to serialize object to XML or Json and save then that way:
https://www.google.com/search?q=c-sharp+how+to+serialize+objects+into+json&ie=&oe=

Good luck - if you get stuck on something specific just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would have voted up but i dont have enough rep yet.

Comment: No problem! I'm not here for the rep - just trying to help and learn. Cheers!

Comment: @Bonbin Did it for you.